# Excel Error in VBA " Run-time error '424': Object required

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and coding in general. I am currently trying to transfer date from a multitab over to a workbook and keep getting the run time error 424: object required. Please help

```
Dim sheetname As String

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim sheetname As String
Select Case MultiPage1.Value
  Case 0`sheetname = "Hannah"
    Sheets(sheetname).Select
    LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A1").Select`enter code here`
    Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = Date
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Me.RequestorHR.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = Me.CaseHR.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = Me.TypeHR.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value = Me.UrgencyHR.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Value = Me.ReasonsHR.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Value = Me.DeadlineHR.Value
    Clear_Click
  Case 1
    sheetname = "John"
    Sheets(sheetname).Select
    LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = Date
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Me.RequestorJM.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = Me.CaseJM.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = Me.TypeJM.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value = Me.UrgencyJM.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Value = Me.ReasonsJM.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Value = Me.DeadlineJM.Value
    Clear_Click
```

Comment: What line is throwing the error?

Comment: Is this just a typo? `Case 0\`sheetname = "Hannah"` ?

Comment: Has to be remove the " ' " and replace it with " : " or add sheetname = "Hannah" under Case 0.

Comment: It doesn't tell me. Usually the error that is causing the issue is highlighted

Comment: That was a typo

Comment: anybody see something I am missing?

Comment: If you have a userform open you cannot select a sheet unless the form is modeless.

Comment: Case is = 0     Maybe

Comment: Actually my comment above is not true.

Answer (score 0):

I made some suggestions below so you have less repeating code.  I added an array so you do not have to keep retyping all your textbox(Assuming) values each time. I hope that helps. I had to guess so if it needs to be tweaked let me know bud! It may run an error cause i was not sure of the active cell your referring too. If you let me know, i can fix it.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim sheetname As String
    Dim strList() As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    strList = Array(, Me.RequestorHR.Value, Me.CaseHR.Value, Me.TypeHR.Value, _
                    Me.UrgencyHR.Value, Me.ReasonsHR.Value, Me.DeadlineHR.Value)

    Select Case MultiPage1.Value

    Case 0

    sheetname = "Hannah"

    Sheets(sheetname).Select

    LastRow = Sheets(sheetname).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Sheets(sheetname).Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = Date

    For i = 1 To 6
        With Sheets(sheetname)
            .ActiveCell.Offset(0, i).Value = strList(i)
        End With
    Next i

    Clear_Click

    Case 1

    sheetname = "John"

    Sheets(sheetname).Select

    LastRow = Sheets(sheetname).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Sheets(sheetname).Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = Date

    For i = 1 To 6
        With Sheets(sheetname)
            .ActiveCell.Offset(0, i).Value = strList(i)
        End With
    Next i

    Clear_Click
```

In Userform Code:

```
 ' StartUpPosition > Manual
 Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
 With Me
    .Top = Int(((Application.Height / 2) + Application.Top) - (.Height / 2))
    .Left = Int(((Application.Width / 2) + Application.Left) - (.Width / 2))
 End With
End sub
```

Code in worksheet or Module:

```
 Sub Open_Userform
     UserForm1.Show False
 End sub
```

Have a great day!

Comment: Case is = 0   Could be your issue also

Comment: I did get an error though that reads  "Compile error: Sub or Function not defined".   The first line is highlighted "Private Sub CommandButton2_Click() and also Clear_Click under Case 0

Comment: What should it read? I feel like it is so close to working! I also have some combo boxes that had dropdowns for Type needed, urgency and reasons....how would I go about adding an array for that?

Comment: @Tquiroz - `Clear_Click` is something you had in your original code.  Is that a subroutine that you didn't include in your posted code?  (Maybe you have a button which you called `Clear`, and you are calling its `Click` event?)

Comment: Right now I just have headers in Row1, A-H titled: Date, Requestor, Case, Type Needed, Urgency, Reasons and Deadline. I need all of the information to transfer to the first available row.

Comment: I want the information to clear once I select the transfer button with is commandbutton2. What do I need to do for that? I think I was under the impression that Clear_Click did that

Comment: Removed Clear_Click and now receiving the error Run time error 1004: Application defined or object  defined error, highlighting the line         
    
    Sheets(sheetname).Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = Date

Comment: Or add "Call Clear_Click" if it is calling a sub

Comment: I am actually working on it right now. I have removed Clear_click and now receiving a Run time error '9': Subscript out of range. Please advise what this means. The highlighted line is Sheets(sheetname). Select. and I was in the tab highlighted Hannah , case 0. Please help

Comment: I have tried it in each of the different tabs and get the same error,highlighting the same line.

Comment: Are the textBoxs on a multipage forme?

Comment: May try  something like  - Me.MultiPage1.Pages(1)..RequestorJM.Value IF you already have a sheetname Hannah it is going to error. You are adding a name that already exists. You would need to just use Sheets("Hannah").select

Comment: Is it possible to email the spreadsheet directly to you? I'm sorry I am working with limited timeframe

Comment: rwyoungblood8@gmail.com - what version Office are you using? i have 10 and 13 on this computer

Comment: Make sure to manually fill in on the worksheet exactly how you want it to look. that will make it much easier to fix real fast. i will leave notes on how and why i did what i did to fix the error.

Comment: Is it too much?

Comment: Nope check your inbox.  You can fill in all the blanks. I wrote it out so it is really easy to read. once you figure out everything you want the drop boxes to say i can show you a simple way of shorten the code.